# can't reach nested <p> element by class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm triyng (without success) to reach and hide all nested elements with class "remove" inside a div

this is the the snippet of code that append the elements

```
$('<li id="com'+msg[key]['id']+'"></li>').prependTo('.mCSB_container').html('<div class="acomments"> <img src="'+url_Avatar+'" alt="Avatar fotomontaggio" /></div><div class="tcomments"><h1>'+nome+'</h1><p class="text">'+commento+'</p><p class="differenza">'+dif+'</p>**<p class="remove" id="r'+msg[key]['id']+'">rimuovi commento</p></div>');
```

and this is the script that tries to hide those elements

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('.remove').hide();});
```

could someone help me please? i can't get out of this...

Comment: Are you sure you don't execute the creation after the hiding ?

Comment: @dystroy I am sure that's the exact scenario.

Comment: Works fine when I test it in a jsFiddle. Can you create a working example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have

```
$(function() {
    ...
    $('<li id="com'+msg[key]['id']+'"></li>').prependTo('.mCSB_container').html('<div class="acomments"> <img src="'+url_Avatar+'" alt="Avatar fotomontaggio" /></div><div class="tcomments"><h1>'+nome+'</h1><p class="text">'+commento+'</p><p class="differenza">'+dif+'</p>**<p class="remove" id="r'+msg[key]['id']+'">rimuovi commento</p></div>');

    ...
});

$(document).ready(function() { $('.remove').hide();});
```

The hiding code is running before the addition (ready comes before load). This means it hides nothing.

The solution is to ensure you execute the hiding code after the creation of elements :

```
$(function() {
    ...
    $('<li id="com'+msg[key]['id']+'"></li>').prependTo('.mCSB_container').html('<div class="acomments"> <img src="'+url_Avatar+'" alt="Avatar fotomontaggio" /></div><div class="tcomments"><h1>'+nome+'</h1><p class="text">'+commento+'</p><p class="differenza">'+dif+'</p>**<p class="remove" id="r'+msg[key]['id']+'">rimuovi commento</p></div>');

    ...
    $('.remove').hide();
});
```

Comment: man..YOU ARE THE ONE!!!!! I spent about 1 hour trying to find an answer. I knew that it would be an easy one but...man...maybe i was blind. THANKS!!!